# How can I read Restricted excel using C#? Oledb driver or interop is the best approach?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, oledb

I have an excel file which restricted one.When i am using oledb connection not able extract data to the Datatable.Another solution is to use interop, but it is very slow and not recommended.Request you to help to read the restricted excel into a datatable.

Comment: Why is it "restricted"? What have you already tried? As is your question is meaningless. Sorry but you need to provide waaaaay more details.

Comment: I am using a web service to download the excel file, the downloaded file is restricted for some user level.I have tried to read the file using OLEDB driver, and getting error external table is not an expected format.But when i am trying with interop able to read the file and the performance is extremely bad. Thanks in advance.